# sendmail add a second attachment to an email

Tags: linux, sendmail, universe

Have a program that issues the following command at the linux level

```
EXE1= "SH -c '/usr/lib/sendmail ":EMAIL<1,X>:' < "/thisdata/level1/VRE/&HOLD&/':PC.FILE:'.CSV':'"':"'"
```

Is it possible to attach a second PC.File in this instruction?

Answer (score 1):

The rightest answer to this would require knowledge of OS and any mail server restrictions you might have but I have been working on an old routine of ours that maybe provide some insight.

We used to us uuencode as @RedCabbage suggested but we had problems with some servers rejecting the messages. As we have no control over other people's servers and because uuencode is almost as old as dirt we updated our solution to use MIME instead. See "Not As Easy Way"

**Easy way**

On our Linux system we use mailx (which in our case linked to /usr/bin/mail) to add multiple attachments.

```
echo "It's Wednessday, my dudes." |mail -s "foobar" -a foo.txt -a bar.txt dudes@wednessday.com
```

This results in an email with two attachments and message body if the files are properly pathed (if used with a real address).

**Not As Easy Way**

Create your own MIME (multipart/mixed) message. We create a record similar to this.

```
To: foo@foo.bar
From: bar@foo.bar
Subject: Not Rocket Surgery
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="SomelongBoundryMarkerYouMakeUpDoNotUseThis"

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

--SomelongBoundryMarkerYouMakeUpDoNotUseThis
Content-Type: text/plain

The body of that message go here. 

--SomelongBoundryMarkerYouMakeUpDoNotUseThis
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="YourFileName.pdf"
Content-Base: http://www.IputOurDomainHereDunnoWhyDoNotUseThis.com


##BASE64 encoded string go here. 
--SomelongBoundryMarkerYouMakeUpDoNotUseThis

Rinse and Repeat with more files, newlines are important here.
```

For the encoding part, assuming that your file is in /foo/bar.pdf

```
ENCODED = ""
FILE.LOC = "/foo/bar.pdf"
TEST = ENCODE("Base64",1,FILE.LOC,2,ENCODED,1)
IF TEST EQ 0 THEN
   ;*Put the text in ENCODED where it says ##BASE64 encoded string go here
END
```

This is much more tedious because you have to figure out the all the mime types and make sure everything is formatted just right.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have managed multiple attachments. For example, `/home/jbloggs/attachment1.doc` `/home/jbloggs/attachment2.pdf`.

You will (as you have done) have to build the commands and execute them with `SH -c 'blah'` (as you have done already.)

1. Create a text file with the address, subject and body in (for example) `/home/jbloggs/tempemail.txt`

> ```
> To: recipient.email@gmail.com
> subject: Your subject line here 
>                                                                            
> This is the main body text
> ```

2. Cycle through the attachments and `uuencode` them to an incrementing name (`ENCODEDn` here):

> ```
> uuencode /home/jbloggs/attachment1.doc attachment1.doc > ENCODED1
> uuencode /home/jbloggs/attachment2.pdf attachment2.pdf > ENCODED2
> ```

3. Use `cat` to join all the files together to a single one:

> ```
> cat /home/jbloggs/tempemail.txt ENCODED1 ENCODED2 > COMBOFILE
> ```

4. Use `sendmail` on the combo:

> ```
> sendmail recipient.email@gmail.com < COMBOFILE
> ```

You can loop through as many `ENCODEDn` files as you like.